# Outlook or OWA: How can I convert an e-mail message to a draft?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, outlook-web-access

There's an option in Thunderbird called `Edit as new...` which converts a message to a draft.

I am looking for something similar in Exchange.

**Reasoning:** We migrated old e-mail of a user from an IMAP server to Exchange. The user had many drafts saved. According to exchange though, the messages are not drafts anymore. My hunch is that, if we find a similar procedure as Thunderbird's `Edit as new...`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Outlook 2010, do the following:

1. Right click on a given message, "Move", and select "Drafts". (If
   it's not in the quicklist, click "Other Folder" and select it.)
2. Open
   the message in the Drafts folder.
3. Click the "Actions" pulldown in
   the top ribbon, and select "Edit Message".

It's a hack, and it's far from perfect (as Outlook doesn't remember that it's editable, so you'd have to click "Edit Message" every time). I'm not sure how to do it in OWA, but I'm sure there's equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Open the message you wish to edit, go to the Message section of the ribbon menu.
Then in the “move” section, choose the bottom right icon “other move options” (these names might be slightly off, I'm translating back from the French GUI I have here) and choose “send this message again”.

It will give you Thunderbird's simple “edit as new” function.